# Mapped drive shows an X

Tags: windows-7, file-sharing

Running Windows 7 (64 and 32-bit), experiencing an issue with mapped drives. Even though I can access the mapped drives contents fine, they show with a red **X** (see image). Does anyone know the solution for this issue?

[image]

Comment: It seems it is a problem with Vista, allegedly fixed on a SP (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/938062 -- although friends corroborate still exists after SP), but present on Windows 7.

Answer (score 1):

This old Microsoft support [article](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;297684) says:

> On a computer that runs one of the
>   versions of Windows that is listed at
>   the beginning of this article, if you
>   map a drive to a network share, the
>   mapped drive may be disconnected after
>   a regular interval of inactivity, and
>   Windows Explorer may display a red "X"
>   on the icon of the mapped drive.
>   However, if you try to access or
>   browse the mapped drive, it reconnects
>   quickly.
>
> This behavior occurs because Windows
>   NT Server 4.0, Windows 2000 Server,
>   and Windows Server 2003 can drop idle
>   connections after a specified time-out
>   period (by default, 15 minutes) to
>   prevent wasting server resources on
>   unused sessions.
>
> To resolve this behavior, change the
>   default time-out period on the shared
>   network computer. To do this, use one
>   of the following methods.

It then describes a regedit operation that seems still valid on my Vista machine, but which I can't actually test.

Comment: No, this occurs on a newly mapped resource. And it does not goes away.

Comment: Question: is the newly mapped resource marked as persistent?

Comment: Yes, mapped as persistent.

Comment: I believe that the above article is probably just as true for new and old mapped drives. Why would the fact that the mapping is new on the client side, change the way that the server works with network connections?

Comment: I can't answer your question. What I tried to say is, the behavior is observed on newly mapped resources, as well as on resources that were mapped for a while. I know it is an issue on Windows Vista/7, since I have research it. I am just looking for a "home medicine" for an issue, for which Microsoft provides little to no help.

Comment: Have you tried on the server machine the remedy suggested in the article? (don't forget to first take a restore point)

Answer (score 0):

After you access the drive, have you tried hitting F5 to refresh the My Computer page?  I think I've seen this in the past and Windows just needed to redraw the page.

Comment: Yes, tried, no change.